# cannot be resolved or is not a field with layout textview and button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm getting four errors all with this message: cannot be resolved or is not a field

The errors are in two different .java files

StartScreen.java.text

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startscreen); (startscreen underlined in red)
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_game); (play_game underlined in red)
```

I creaded a textview called startscreen and a button called startButton inside game.xml

PlayGame.java

```
tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_text); (game_text underlined in red)
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end_game); (end_game underlined in red)
```

I creaded a textview called game_text and a button called end_game inside game.xml

StartScreen.java

```
package com.example.startscreenapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class StartScreen extends Activity {
private static final int PLAY_GAME = 1010;
private TextView tv;
private int meaningOfLife = 42;
private String userName = "Douglas Adams";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startscreen.text);
//Display initial values
tv.setText(userName + ":" + meaningOfLife);
//Set up button listener
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_game);

startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
startGame();
}
});
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == PLAY_GAME && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
meaningOfLife = data.getExtras().getInt("returnInt");
userName = data.getExtras().getString("returnStr");
//Show it has changed
tv.setText(userName + ":" + meaningOfLife);
}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
private void startGame() {
Intent launchGame = new Intent(this, PlayGame.class);
//passing information to launched activity
launchGame.putExtra("meaningOfLife", meaningOfLife);
launchGame.putExtra("userName", userName);
startActivityForResult(launchGame, PLAY_GAME);
}
}
```

PlayGame.java

```
package com.example.startscreenapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class PlayGame extends Activity {
private TextView tv2;
int answer;
String author;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.game);
tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_text);
//reading information passed to this activity
//Get the intent that started this activity
Intent i = getIntent();
//returns -1 if not initialized by calling activity
answer = i.getIntExtra("meaningOfLife", -1);
//returns [] if not initialized by calling activity
author = i.getStringExtra("userName");
tv2.setText(author + ":" + answer);
//Change values for an example of return
answer = answer - 41;
author = author + " Jr.";
//Set up button listener
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end_game);
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
//Return information to calling activity
Intent i = getIntent();
i.putExtra("returnInt", answer);
i.putExtra("returnStr", author);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
}
});
}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startscreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/startscreen"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startscreen"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

game.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/end_game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show xml file, too. remove .text and clean + build.

Comment: I updated the post above with the xml files. Also cleaned the project.

Comment: Please remove .text from `startscreen.text`

Comment: I got rid of the .text.

Comment: try importing your .R file not the android's .R, usually its **com.yourAppName.R**

Answer (score 0):

Your textview id on your xml is `startscreen`

Instead of `v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startscreen.text);` just remove the `.text` part

Comment: This didn't fix the error. startscreen without .text is still underlined in red with same error.

Answer (score 0):

in `startscreen.java` you have `tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startscreen.text);` and in your `activity_main.xml` you have `android:id="@+id/startscreen"`.

what you should do :

1-is removing the `.text` from `tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startscreen.text);`

2- `clean` and `build` you project again. (if this didn't work , close and open eclipse again.

i suggest to use `ctrl + space` in completing you statement, that would help in reducing error and give suggestion.